# How can I pass a proxied response when 'selfHandleResponse' is true?

Tags: node.js, express, request, node-http-proxy, http-proxy-middleware

I am running a development proxy-server where on startup I make a request for an auth token with our cluster architecture.

However, this token expires after some time. Then instead of the developer restarting their proxy-server, I would like to make another request to get another valid auth token. To be able to handle the response by myself I set the `node-http-proxy` option `selfHandleResponse` to true.

```
app.use(
  '/',
  index({
    target: config.hostname,
    changeOrigin: true,
    onProxyReq,
    onProxyRes,
    selfHandleResponse: true
  })
);
```

Now, I only want to handle responses with a `401`, because it is the only case I need to request another token.

```
const onProxyRes = (proxyRes, req, res) => {
  if (proxyRes.statusCode === 401) {
    getToken()
      .then(forwardRequest(req))
      .then((response) => {
        res.send(response.body);
      })
      .catch(() => {        
        res.sendStatus(500);
      });
  }

  // How to pass back the original proxyRes including body, headers etc.?
});
```

EDIT: forwardRequest is my function to retry the original request and then hand it back to the client when successful.

My trouble starts here, since I have no idea on how to pass the proxied non-401 request back to the client. I found myself starting to implement body parsing logic dependent on header content-type, but I very much hope there is an easier way.

Any ideas?

Comment: Could you share how your `forwardRequest` function looks? Might make it easier for people stumbling over the same issue.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The solution is simple...

```
proxyRes.pipe(res);
```

Found in the source code of `node-http-proxy`.